# search specific post in facebook using gaph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to search for a specific post on my page which starts with specified text. I am able to search all public post by using

https://grpah.facebook.com/search?q=specified text&type=post

or

getting all feeds of my page

https://graph.facebook.com/[page-name]/feed?auth_token=[auth_token_received from facebook]

but I am unable to search for posts that are on my page and have specified text. Is there a way to achieve this